# How to automate combine harvesting?

Tags: farming-simulator-2013

When the AI drives the combine, he automatically stops and opens the pipe when the harvester storage becomes full. This requires human input to offload the harvested material.
Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default, but just stumbled upon a mod called [course:play](http://courseplay.github.io/courseplay) which allows you to automate quite a bit, including a combi mode:

> The combi mode is very similar to the Driving helper mode, in that the tractor drives a course and unloads at a trigger. But, in addition, the driver unloads a working combine or chopper on the field.

I have tested it myself, and although it can be a bit tricky to set up the first time, it works pretty great once you get how it going.

Answer (score -2):

You can empty the harvester by driving the trailer under the auger; you can go back to harvesting afterward.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; how do you *automate* offloading the harvested material? That is, how do you make it happen without you having to do anything?